# How to import multiple values in a text field with Feeds module?

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting, entities

In my content type, I have a text field that allow an illimited number of values.

How do I configure Feeds to import multiple datas in this kind of field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Feeds Tamper](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) will do this for you.

> Feeds Tamper provides a small plugin architecture for Feeds to modify
>   data before it gets saved. Several plugins are available by default
>   and are described in the examples section below. Additional plugins
>   can be added in separate modules or through the issue queue.

One of the default plugins is explode.  Just set up a feed tamper to take your multivalued field from your CSV and explode it based on whatever delimiter you fancy.  This will import it as multiple field values.

Comment: I was looking for a solution programmatically, but Feeds Tamper easily do the job. Tanks Chapabu!

Comment: What a fantastically useful addition to the Feeds module!